# How to prove that $1+\tan^2a=\dfrac{1}{\cos^2a}$ ?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Prove the following statement: $$1+\tan^2a=\dfrac{1}{\cos^2a}$$

I tried but I failed to find answer cause I don't know how to prove trigonometric equalities.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you know, $\tan A=\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}$ and $\sin ^2A+\cos^2A=1$

Comment: yes i know those rules

Comment: Never forget this last one ! It is one of the most used in trigonometry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\color{blue}1+\color{red}{\tan^2a}=\color{blue}{\dfrac{\cos^2a}{\cos^2a}}+\color{red}{\dfrac{\sin^2a}{\cos^2a}}$$

Comment: aaa!! didnt think about it!!